# Spark- Split or replace part of the column based on multiple delimiters

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe as input below. Ultimately, I'm trying to get the output as below, so I can use `df.filter(col("A").contains(col("B")))` to see if `A` contains `B` as substring. Noted here I'd like to check the order of the letters as well so `set` probably will not work. For example "acb" should not be considered as a substring of "abcd" I've tried to use `split` but it only takes one delimiter. Could some please help? I'm using spark 2.4.

Input

```
  +---+-------+-----------+
  | id|.  A   |    B      |
  +---+-------+-----------+
  |  1|abc d  |  bc, z    |
  |  2|abc-d  | acb       |
  |  3|abcde  |  hj f     |
  +---+-------+-----------+
```

Output

```
  +---+-------+-----------+
  | id|.  A   |    B      |
  +---+-------+-----------+
  |  1|abcd   |  bcz     |
  |  2|abcd   | acb       |
  |  3|abcde  |  hjf     |
  +---+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: I understand from the text that you want to remove lines where A contains B string (I'm not sure about the splitting part, though). But in the output example, no lines were filtered. It looks like you only want to remove non-letter characters. For the rest, the question if properly written. So I won't vote to close. But please clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for both split and replace.

> If you want to split, your output is not right.

- **Split**

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"id": 1, "A": "abc d", "B": "bc, z"},
    {"id": 2, "A": "abc-d", "B": "acb"},
    {"id": 3, "A": "abcde", "B": "hj f"},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
split_regex = "((,)?\s|[-])"
df = df.withColumn("A", F.split(F.col("A"), split_regex))
df = df.withColumn("B", F.split(F.col("B"), split_regex))
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- B: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)

+--------+-------+---+
|A       |B      |id |
+--------+-------+---+
|[abc, d]|[bc, z]|1  |
|[abc, d]|[acb]  |2  |
|[abcde] |[hj, f]|3  |
+--------+-------+---+
```

Now you can create a UDF that will check if values in array `B` are substrings in values in array `A`.

- **Replace**

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"id": 1, "A": "abc d", "B": "bc, z"},
    {"id": 2, "A": "abc-d", "B": "acb"},
    {"id": 3, "A": "abcde", "B": "hj f"},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
replace_regex = "((,)?\s|[-])"
df = df.withColumn("A", F.regexp_replace(F.col("A"), replace_regex, ""))
df = df.withColumn("B", F.regexp_replace(F.col("B"), replace_regex, ""))
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)

+-----+---+---+                                                                 
|A    |B  |id |
+-----+---+---+
|abcd |bcz|1  |
|abcd |acb|2  |
|abcde|hjf|3  |
+-----+---+---+
```

This is a bit involved, and I would stick to `split` since here `abcd` contains both `b` and `bc` and there's no way for you to keep track of the whole words if you completely replace the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that after replace, `contains` would not return true for the first row. How do you check if `abcd` contains `bcz`, as there's 'bc' as intersect, I'd like it to return true.

Comment: @user4046073 `contains` way is a bit involved and I would stick to `split`. Please see the example on your previous question that is related to this one.

Comment: Edit the comment from above:
`replace`* way is a bit involved...